# passing message with postMessage() in cross origin manner

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

I am developing a chrome extension, in which I am working on two windows. The second window has been opened by the first window, through JavaScript. What I want to do is, to get the URL of the window opened by the first window. I have tried some methods, like using cookies, local Storage but I failed because of the cross origin policy. Now I came to know after a tutorial on postMessage() API of JavaScript that it overcomes the policy of cross origin. What I am doing is, I am accessing the URL from my localhost, and trying to get the URL of any other site, or possible I can get a simple message from that, but its not working for me as well. As I am not even getting any error and not even a warning. My goal is to get the URL, after when the child window loads. I will require on load function, so that I can check when the window is loaded right after it send me the message to my current window where it has been opened from.

**My Code**

```js
var win = window.open('https://javascript.info/','_blank');
    win.focus();
    win.postMessage('The URL of the window is : ' + document.URL,'http://localhost.com/ext_files/index.php');

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        if (event.origin != 'https://javascript.info/') {
          // something from an unknown domain, let's ignore it
          return;
        }
        alert(event.data);
});
```

Comment: What does that mean @wOxxOm

Comment: I guess that's the reason I came here for to get the solution for it @wOxxOm

Comment: If I understand correctly, your postMessage parameter ''http://localhost.com/ext_files/index.php" means that only scripts on that URL will receive the message. So you have to make sure that the script which installs the listener is being run on that URL.


I suggest starting off by changing 'http://localhost.com/ext_files/index.php' to '*' (wild card target origin). Verify that you do indeed get messages, then restrict your target origin to debug your issue.